# Cant post data from angular to node api

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to post data from angular to node API, the data is not getting posted

I have setup a node API, designed a simple textbox and button on angular,when clicked, the textbox value should be posted to node API, the data is not getting posted, also no response from subscribe method in angular

ins.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable,Subject} from 'rxjs';
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class InsService {
      name: String;
      constructor(private http:Http) { }
      postAPIData(name: String):Observable<any>{
        console.log("hi");
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/', {"name":name})
      }
    }
```

ins.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {InsService} from '../ins.service'
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-ins',
      templateUrl: './ins.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./ins.component.css']
    })
    export class InsComponent {
      ivalue:String;
      ins:InsService;
      constructor()
      {

      }

    insoperation(insertion:String)
    {
      if(insertion)
      {
        this.ivalue=insertion;
        console.log(this.ivalue);
        this.postdata();
      }
    }  
    postdata()
    {
        ()=>{this.ins.postAPIData(this.ivalue).subscribe((response)=>{
          console.log('response from post data is ', response);
        })};
    }

    }
```

server.js

```
    var express=require("express");
    var app=express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var cors = require("cors");
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.listen(3000,"localhost",function(req,res,next){
        console.log("Server running on port 3000");
    })
    app.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
      next();
    });
    app.post('/',function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body);
    })
```

i expect the data to be posted from angular to node

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line `inst: InService` only telling TypeScript the type of the variable. You need to define the service in your **constructor** to use it.

Than you can get rid of the arrow function in your `postdata()` function :

```
inst: InService // Remove this line, instead define it in your constructor

constructor(private ins:InsService  ) {}

postdata(){
    this.ins.postAPIData(this.ivalue).subscribe((response)=>{
          console.log('response from post data is ', response);
    })};
}
```

Comment: Sir, but i am trying to trigger the api call only when the button is clicked

Comment: Then remove the arrow function in your postdata function, and you still need to define the service in your constructor to get it working. Updated answer

Comment: if i remove the arrow function type error this.ins is not defined is throwing up

Comment: Not if you define it in your **constructor**

Comment: yeah sir, it worked, the error is not throwing up now, but still i cant able to publish data to node api

Comment: sir it worked!!, i did as you told, now i am able to publish data from angular to node api

Comment: Glad to hear that, would you mark my answer as corrected answer please ? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Define the service in your constructor

```
constructor(private ins:InsService  ) {}
```

and remove the reference from

```
  ins:InsService; // this line
```

You need to change the postdata method on angular to

```
(()=>{this.ins.postAPIData(this.ivalue).subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log('response from post data is ', response);
    })})();
```

or

```
postdata()
{
    this.ins.postAPIData(this.ivalue).subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log('response from post data is ', response);
    });
}
```

You are defining an arrow function which is not getting executed

Comment: I tried it already sir @jithin, without arrow function, it's throwing a type error this.ins is not defined

Comment: have you added your service to providers array in main module

Comment: add the service to the constructor and remove it from the global declaration

Comment: add  `providers: [
    InsService]` to your app.module.ts file